# Transition height of wrapper div when child height changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I suspect CSS3 transitions aren't the answer to this, but here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

In a wrapper/child div scenario, the child div is swapped out for a div of a different, unknown, height. This causes an abrupt height change. I want that height change to transition smoothly, a la CSS3 property transitions.

Here's the bin:
  http://jsbin.com/hakanulodo/9/edit

And to address link rot, here's the bin's initial code:

```
# HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child">
      Original
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="new">
    New
  </div>
</body>
</html>

# css
.wrapper {
  transition: height 0.25s ease 0.2s;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
}

.new {
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

# javascript
$('.wrapper').click( function() {
  var item = $('.new').css("display", "block");
  $('.wrapper').html(item);  
});
```

I'm open to JS solutions as well as CSS. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

- you can't transition attribute ('display' none to 'block').
- why do you want to use a div outside the 'wrapper' class? is it ok to just add a class and change the div's name?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="child">
      Original
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.50s ease 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: height 0.50s ease 0.2s;
  transition: height 0.50s ease 0.2s;
}

.new {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$('.child').click( function() {
  $(this).addClass('new').html('New');
});
```

example: http://jsbin.com/jivevasawi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Thanks for responding! 1. I'm not transitioning the display attribute, but point taken. 2. In this case, I'm getting an entirely new object back from the server, which I need to swap into a placeholder, so changing the class isn't an option, though that certainly would make it easier.

Comment: ok, here it is with jquery:
http://jsbin.com/gazuhoxuli/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Nice! This is very clever, I didn't know about .promise(). However, you still need to know the eventual height. Is there a way to do this without knowing the end height?

Comment: because i don't know what you are trying to do exactly then i can't see the the big picture here and exact the result you need, but if you don't know the height and it's going to come with the new object you can replace the 200 'px' with variable, the variable's value will get the height from the new object.

Comment: in the next example we have the new object with height of 200 'px', we get it's height (200 'px' in this case) and put it inside a var. then we set the height of new object to the child's height (for the starting point of the animation - 100 'px' in this case), when click on the 'wrapper' the new object will be removed inside the 'wrapper'and after it will be done it will start the animate to the new object's original height (the var we had set in the first place)  
example: http://jsbin.com/xuhodoyose/1/edit?html,css,js,output